# How to describe algorithms, prove and analyse them?

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, runtime-analysis

Before reading *The Art of Computer Programming (TAOCP)*, I have not considered these questions deeply. I would use pseudo code to describe algorithms, understand them and estimate the running time only about orders of growth. The *TAOCP* thoroughly changes my mind.

*TAOCP* uses English mixed with steps and *goto* to describe the algorithm, and uses flow charts to picture the algorithm more readily. It seems low-level, but I find that there's some advantages, especially with flow chart, which I have ignored a lot. We can label each of the arrows with an assertion about the current state of affairs at the time the computation traverses that arrow, and make an inductive proof for the algorithm. The author says:

> It is the contention of the author that we really understand why an algorithm is valid only when we reach the point that our minds have implicitly filled in all the assertions, as was done in Fig.4.

I have not experienced such stuff. Another advantage is that, we can count the number of times each step is executed. It's easy to check with Kirchhoff's first law. I have not analysed the running time exactly, so some $\pm1$ might have been omitted when I was estimating the running time.

Analysis of orders of growth is sometimes useless. For example, we cannot distinguish quicksort from heapsort because they are all $E(T(n))=\Theta(n\log n)$, where $EX$ is the expected number of random variable $X$, so we should analyse the constant, say, $E(T_1(n))=A_1n\lg n+B_1n+O(\log n)$ and $E(T_2(n))=A_2\lg n+B_2n+O(\log n)$, thus we can compare $T_1$ and $T_2$ better. And also, sometimes we should compare other quantities, such as variances. Only a rough analysis of orders of growth of running time is not enough. As *TAOCP* translates the algorithms into assembly language and calculate the running time, It's too hard for me, so I want to know some techniques to analyse the running time a bit more roughly, which is also useful, for higher-level languages such as C, C++ or pseudo codes.

And I want to know what style of description is mainly used in research works, and how to treat these problems.

Comment: You should be very careful when comparing execution times of algorithms this closely. Real computers have caches, registers and pipelines, which can change the running time drastically. If you want to find out which algorithm is actually faster, you have to actually run it on a computer.

Comment: Actually, analysing assembler such as Knuth uses is *way* easier than analysing real-life code because nothing is hidden and control flow is easy. You are asking for practice; I think [Dave's comment](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74/is-smoothed-analysis-used-outside-academia#comment150_74) applies. Practitioners are more likely to engineer their algorithms using runtime measurements than to do rigorous analysis. But then, I am no practitioner so take what I say with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Raphael My *in practice* means that *in practice of research works*, not *programming*.

Comment: @Frank, what do you mean by _variance_? My performance tests give me timing variances.

Comment: @Raphael, your first point this is no longer really true. Modern chips reorder your assembly, do stores/loads out-of-order, and predictive running and loading. For concurrency, and the previous issues, thorough analysis is actually required, but I don't do it in a formal form.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance The performance tests only give the sample variance $\hat VX$, but the input of an algorithm is too large. I want to analyse an algorithm roughly, but exact enough to determine the main constant, just like *TAOCP*, although omitting something, say, caching.

Comment: @FrankScience, do you know that each assembler instruction requires a different number of cycles on the chip? This time can actually be variable as well. For some instructions the variance comes from the input and some from the caches.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Yes. Strictly speaking, I want to know a common model, which is *close* to the real world and is usually true, say, comparing quicksort and heapsort, and without too much consideration on assembly language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3782/discussion-between-eda-qa-mort-ora-y-and-frank-science)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a huge variety of feasible approaches. Which is best suited depends on

- *what* you are trying to show,
- how much *detail* you want or need.

If the algorithm is a widely known one which you use as a subroutine, you often remain at a higher level. If the algorithm is the main object under investigation, you probably want to be more detailed. The same can be said for analyses: if you need a rough upper runtime bound you proceed differently from when you want precise counts of statements.

I will give you three examples for the well-known algorithm Mergesort which hopefully illustrate this.

#### High Level

The algorithm Mergesort takes a list, splits it in two (about) equally long parts, recurses on those partial lists and merges the (sorted) results so that
the end-result is sorted. On singleton or empty lists, it returns the input.

This algorithm is obviously a correct sorting algorithm. Splitting the list and merging it can each be implemented in time $\Theta(n)$, which gives us a recurrence for worst case runtime $T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \Theta(n)$. By the Master theorem, this evaluates to $T(n) \in \Theta(n\log n)$.

#### Medium Level

The algorithm Mergesort is given by the following pseudo-code:

```
procedure mergesort(l : List) {
  if ( l.length < 2 ) {
    return l
  }

  left  = mergesort(l.take(l.length / 2)
  right = mergesort(l.drop(l.length / 2)
  result = []

  while ( left.length > 0 || right.length > 0 ) {
    if ( right.length == 0 || (left.length > 0 && left.head <= right.head) ) {
      result = left.head :: result
      left = left.tail
    }
    else {
      result = right.head :: result
      right = right.tail
    }
  }

  return result.reverse
}
```

We prove correctness by induction. For lists of length zero or one, the algorithm is trivially correct. As induction hypothesis, assume `mergesort` performs correctly on lists of length at most $n$ for some arbitrary, but fixed natural $n>1$. Now let $L$ be a list of length $n+1$. By induction hypothesis, `left` and `right` hold (non-decreasingly) sorted versions of the first resp. second half of $L$ after the recursive calls. Therefore, the `while` loop selects in every iteration the smallest element not yet investigated and appends it to `result`; thus `result` is a non-increasingly sorted list containing all elements from `left` and `right`. The reverse is a non-decreasingly sorted version of $L$, which is the returned -- and desired -- result.

As for runtime, let us count element comparisons and list operations (which dominate the runtime asymptotically). Lists of length less than two cause neither. For lists of length $n>1$, we have those operations caused by preparing the inputs for the recursive calls, those from the recursive calls themselves plus the `while` loop and one `reverse`. Both recursive parameters can be computed with at most $n$ list operations each. The `while` loop is executed exactly $n$ times and every iteration causes at most one element comparison and exactly two list operations. The final `reverse` can be implemented to use $2n$ list operations -- every element is removed from the input and put into the output list. Therefore, the operation count fulfills the following recurrence:

$\qquad \begin{align}T(0) = T(1) &= 0 \\
T(n) &\leq T\left(\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\right) + T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) + 7n\end{align}$

As $T$ is clearly non-decreasing, it is sufficient to consider $n=2^k$ for asymptotic growth. [In this case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9569/98), the recurrence simplifies to

$\qquad \begin{align}T(0) = T(1) &= 0 \\
T(n) &\leq 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + 7n\end{align}$

By the Master theorem, we get $T \in \Theta(n \log n)$ which extends to the runtime of `mergesort`.

#### Ultra-low level

Consider this (generalised) implementation of Mergesort in [Isabelle/HOL](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/):

```
types dataset  =  "nat * string"

fun leq :: "dataset \<Rightarrow> dataset \<Rightarrow> bool" where
   "leq (kx::nat, dx) (ky, dy) = (kx \<le> ky)"

fun merge :: "dataset list \<Rightarrow> dataset list \<Rightarrow> dataset list" where
"merge [] b = b" |
"merge a [] = a" |
"merge (a # as) (b # bs) = (if leq a b then a # merge as (b # bs) else b # merge (a # as) bs)"

function (sequential) msort :: "dataset list \<Rightarrow> dataset list" where
  "msort []  = []" |
  "msort [x] = [x]" |
  "msort l   = (let mid = length l div 2 in merge (msort (take mid l)) (msort (drop mid l)))"
by pat_completeness auto
  termination
  apply (relation "measure length")
by simp+
```

This already includes proofs of well-definedness and termination. Find an (almost) complete correctness proof [here](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_2374.thy).

For the "runtime", that is number of comparisons, a recurrence similar to the one in the prior section can be set up. Instead of using the Master theorem and forgetting the constants, you can also analyse it to get an approximation that is asymptotically equal the true quantity. You can find the full analysis in [1]; here is a rough outline (it does not necessarily fit the Isabelle/HOL code):

As above, the recurrence for the number of comparisons is

$\qquad \begin{align}f_0 = f_1 &= 0 \\
f_n &= f_{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil} + f_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} + e_n\end{align}$

where $e_n$ is the number of comparisons needed for merging the partial results². In order to get rid of the floors and ceils, we perform a case distinction over whether $n$ is even:

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{cases}
f_{2m}   &= 2f_m + e_{2m} \\
f_{2m+1} &= f_m + f_{m+1} + e_{2m+1}
  \end{cases}$

Using nested [forward/backward differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of $f_n$ and $e_n$ we get that

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k) \cdot \Delta\kern-.2em\nabla f_k = f_n - nf_1$.

The sum matches the right-hand side of [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula). We define the [Dirichlet generating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) of $\Delta\kern-.2em\nabla f_k$ as

$\qquad \displaystyle W(s) = \sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \Delta\kern-.2em\nabla f_k k^{-s} = \frac{1}{1-2^{-s}} \cdot \underbrace{\sum\limits_{k \geq 1} \frac{\Delta\kern-.2em\nabla e_k}{k^s}}_{=:\ \boxminus(s)}$

which together with Perron's formula leads us to

$\qquad \displaystyle f_n = nf_1 + \frac{n}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{3-i\infty}^{3+i\infty} \frac{\boxminus(s)n^s}{(1-2^{-s})s(s+1)}ds$.

Evaluation of $\boxminus(s)$ depends on which case is analysed. Other than that, we can -- after some trickery -- apply the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to get

$\qquad \displaystyle f_n \sim n \cdot \log_2(n) + n \cdot A(\log_2(n)) + 1$

where $A$ is a periodic function with values in $[-1,-0.9]$.

---

1. [Mellin transforms and asymptotics: the mergesort recurrence](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00074948) by Flajolet and Golin (1992)
2. Best case: $e_n = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$
   Worst case: $e_n = n-1$
   Average case: $e_n = n - \frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil + 1} - \frac{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + 1}$

Comment: My question of running-time-analysis is that, how to determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exactly $T(n)=T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)+T(\lceil n/2\rceil)+\alpha n+\beta$, which is close to practice (e.g, it's availabe to compare merge-sort and qsort).

Comment: @Frank: The short answer is **You can't**; the constants depend on implementation details—including the machine architecture, language, and compiler—that are immaterial to the underlying algorithm.

Comment: @JeffE I have to claim that, the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should only be exact enough to do **some** comparison. More briefly, a mathematical model which can do *a lot of works*, without machine languages, to determine the constants.

Comment: @JeffE for example, the MIX/MMIX in taocp is, but it's too hard to translate an algorithm to such a machine language.

Comment: @FrankScience: In order to get close to practice, you would have to count *all* operations (like Knuth does). Then, you can instantiate your result with machine-specific operation costs to get real runtime (ignoring effects the order of operations might have, caching, pipelines, ...). Usually, people only count *some* operations, and in that case fixing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does not tell you much.

Comment: Yes, ignoring caching and so on. My question is stated not only for $T(n)$ but also for count *some operations*. In Knuth's viewpoint, he uses flow chart and Kirchoff's first law, which is easier to check whether the count is right or wrong, but pseudo code is not. I find that pseudo code is easier for us to count roughly (for example, $A \sim m+n$ where $A$ is the times of some operation), but exactly, it's easier to forget something, perhaps $\pm1$. Incidentally, where have you used dgf?

Comment: @FrankScience: I'm not sure what your question is, then. If you want to count operations precisely, you need to use low-level algorithm statement and analysis. Regarding your other comment, I will edit in the key points of the proof. In the meantime, feel free to try and tackle the recursion with elementary mathematics; *I* don't know how to do that. Note that $n=2^k$ is no longer assumed.

Answer (score 3):

Dijkstra's ["A discipline of Programming"](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~cs410aph/Lectures/Smalltalk%20II/Dijkstra%20on%20Hamming%27s%20Problem.pdf) is all about analyzing and proving algorithms and designing for provability.  In the preface to that book, Dijkstra explains how a very simple constructed mini-language that is properly designed to be analyzed suffices to explain many algorithms formally:

> When starting on a book like this, one is immediately faced with the question: "Which programming language am I going to use?", and this is *not* a mere question of presentation!  A most important, but also a most elusive, aspect of any tool is its influence on the habits of those who train themselves in its use.  If the tool is a programming language, this influence is -- whether we like it or not -- an influence on our thinking habits.  Having analyzed that influence to the best of my knowledge, I had come to the conclusion that none of the existing programming languages, nor a subset of them, would suit my purpose; on the other hand I knew myself so unready for the design of a new programming language that I had taken a vow not to do so for the next five years, and I had a most distinct feeling that that period had not yet elapsed! (Prior to that, among many other things, this monograph had to be written.)  I have tried to resolve this conflict by only designing a mini-language suitable for my purposes, by making only those commitments that seemed unavoidable and sufficiently justified.

Later he explains just how small he managed to get his mini-language.

> I owe the reader an explanation why I have kept the mini-language so small that it does not even contain procedures and recursion. ... **The point is that I felt no need of them in order to get my message across, viz. how a carefully chose separation of concerns is essential for the design of in all respect, high-quality programs; the modest tools of the mini-language gave us already more than enough latitude for nontrivial, yet very satisfactory designs.**